# Cannot update system due to kde apps on arch

Tags: arch-linux, kde, software-updates, kde5

I am not able to update my system on arch.
I am using

```
Operating System: Arch Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.109.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10
```

When I am running

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I get

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace attica with extra/attica5? [Y/n] Y
...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing kxmlgui breaks dependency 'kxmlgui' required by kfloppy
...
```

If I am denying the replacements I get

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace attica with extra/attica5? [Y/n] n
...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: kitemmodels5 and kitemmodels are in conflict (kitemmodels<5.111)
```

So I have the feeling that something is mismatching with my kde-framework version. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried switching mirrors or using the main archive? Maybe your mirror isn't fully synced yet

Comment: I did, but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out:

- The root for the problem was that qt5 will be updated to qt6 soon. So the developers decided to suffix all packages with `5`to make them better identifiable
- In this cause also all the telepathy packages will get removed from KDE, because there do not seem to be development for them in the future

So I had to remove all telepathy packages first, as per [this Arch Linux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2127289#p2127289):

```
sudo pacman -Rns $(sudo pacman -Qq | grep "telepathy-*")
```

Then I removed kfloppy by hand:

```
sudo pacman -R kfloppy
```

Finally it worked:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some orphaned packages installed.
You can try removing those packages with this command before updating:
`# pacman -Qtdq | pacman -Rns -`

Read more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Removing_unused_packages_(orphans)

Comment: I indeed got some, but that did not solve the problem